# Javascript click event not working in Blazor client side app

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side

I'm new to Blazor and I've created a pretty simple Webassembly app. I want a href link to go to a div lower down the page when I click on it, but the Javascript click event won't work. In the Index.razor page the `JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("clicker")` is working and the `alert("In clicker")` happens as the page loads, but the click / href to go the "intro" div will not work for love nor money :-/

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Blazor App</title>
    <!--script type='text/javascript' src='./scripts/app.js'-->
</head>
<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script>
        function clicker() {
            alert("In clicker"); // this works
            document.getElementById('skip').onclick = function(e){
                alert("clicked"); // this works but the page still won't scroll to the "intro" div :(
            }
        }
        //clicker();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.razor (@code section is at top of page)

```
@page "/"
@code {
    [Inject]
    protected IJSRuntime JsRuntime { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("clicker");
        }
    }
}

// This link won't go to the intro div when clicked :(
<a id="skip" class="skip" href="#intro">skip this bit</a>
...
<div id="intro" class="home">
...
</div>
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    public void Configure(IComponentsApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.AddComponent<App>("app");
    }
}
```

If anyone could shed some light on this it would save my week.

Comment: I'm confused. Your click event is on the div, but it sounds like you are trying to click on the a link to trigger it? Can you clarify?

Comment: Hi @Kyle the click is on the '<a href="#intro">' element and it should link to the div with the "intro" id when clicked. Does that make sense?

Comment: Wow. Someone is actually using Blazor.

Comment: I also have this issue, will check out the solutions below and see if they work

Comment: @Kyle you're totally right - good spot. I should have an id on the <a> element and use that in the `document.getElementById`. I tried it though and it doesn't make the href work. The only reason I have the clicker function is to try and force the `<a href>` to work somehow. Will now try the suggested answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for JavaScript here.

If you add a specific target to your markup, it will just work.

You can use target="_top" to avoid **Blazor** navigation interception.

```html
<a class="skip" href="#intro" target="_top">skip this bit</a>
...
<div id="intro" class="home">
...
</div>
```

Note that `target="_top"` just directs the browser to navigate within the topmost frame in the window, it does not mean you will scroll to the top!

Answer (score 2):

The page won’t scroll to the element you’ve specified in the link.This has to do with how routing is handled in Blazor and most other SPA applications as well. A simple solution is that you could create your own AnchorLink component and use a little bit of JavaScript interop magic.

1.Create `AnchorLink.razor` in `Pages/Shared`

```
@code {

    public AnchorLink()
    {
        this.Attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    private string targetId = null;
    private bool preventDefault = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// This parameter supports arbitrary attributes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Any attribute specified on the component, which is not defined as a parameter, whill be added to this dictionary.
    /// It is then uses as the source for attributes rendered onto the resulting HTML element below in the markup section
    /// of this component.
    /// For details, refer to <see cref="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components#attribute-splatting-and-arbitrary-parameters"/>.
    /// </remarks>
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public IDictionary<string, object> Attributes { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Supports child content for the component.
    /// </summary>
    /// <see cref="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components#child-content"/>
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    protected IJSRuntime JsInterop { get; set; }


    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        string href = null;
        if (this.Attributes.ContainsKey("href"))
        {
            // If the href attribute has been specified, we examine the value of it. If if starts with '#'
            // we assume the rest of the value contains the ID of the element the link points to.
            href = $"{this.Attributes["href"]}";
            if (href.StartsWith("#"))
            {
                // If the href contains an anchor link we don't want the default click action to occur, but
                // rather take care of the click in our own method.
                this.targetId = href.Substring(1);
                this.preventDefault = true;
            }
        }
        base.OnParametersSet();
    }

    private async Task AnchorOnClickAsync()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.targetId))
        {
            // If the target ID has been specified, we know this is an anchor link that we need to scroll
            // to, so we call the JavaScript method to take care of this for us.
            await this.JsInterop.InvokeVoidAsync("anchorLink.scrollIntoView", this.targetId);
        }
    }

}

<a href="" @onclick="this.AnchorOnClickAsync" @onclick:stopPropagation="false" />
<a @attributes="this.Attributes" @onclick="this.AnchorOnClickAsync" @onclick:preventDefault="this.preventDefault">Hello @this.ChildContent</a>
```

2.Add js in `wwwroot/Index.html`

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
<script>
    window.anchorLink = {
    scrollIntoView: function (elementId) {
        // This function is called from the AnchorLink component using JavaScript interop.
        // It will try to find an element using the ID given to the function, and scroll that
        // element into view, if an element is found.
        var elem = document.getElementById(elementId);
        if (elem) {
            elem.scrollIntoView();
            window.location.hash = elementId;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

3.`Index.razor`

```
<AnchorLink class="skip" href="#intro">skip this bit</AnchorLink>
```

Refer to https://mikaberglund.com/2019/12/28/creating-anchor-links-in-blazor-applications/

Comment: Thanks Xing - the first answer worked so gonna go with that for now, will try your solution in a day or two